# FreePBX distro on CentOS failed to boot with RAID

Tags: centos, lvm, raid1

I have a regular FreePBX (latest 7) distro with LVM RAID1 volume on two physical disks. After power fail it can't boot and drops to emergency mode.

Main LV is inactive and I can't enable it because there is no `dm-raid` module in emergency mode.
Can you advise me how I can fix the system?

[image: screenshot]

I followed this advice from CentOS forum:

1. boot to recovery mode from boot CD (check)
2. chroot to system root (check)
3. mount partitions manually (LVM was mounted automatically)
4. rebuilt initramfs with `dracut -f`

Rebuild doesn't work because error:

`Cannot find /usr/lib/dracut/dractur-init.sh`

Comment: Welcome to U&L. The info you gave in the comment is important, so I added it to your question instead. You can delete the comment. For the future - when you do have info to add, don't put in a comment, just [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739174/edit) the question instead. That way the relevant info is readily available.